# NSString literal with format, crashes in Obj-C class methods

Tags: class, crash, nsstring, arguments, nsobject

I'm getting a crash in some places where I'm using a replacement for NSLog.

(I'm using the replacement primarily to write to file and to an on-screen text field, but for the moment I'm leaving it to just print to the console)

I've tried the following two implementations (thanks to the original authors, by the way):
http://www.platinumball.net/blog/2009/07/18/nslog-sucks/
http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2009/03/23/114/

They both work for me in some locations in my code, but it seems that when I call them from a certain couple of places, they cause a crash, often with CFStringAppendFormatCore at the top of the stack trace, but not always (the most recent time, it was on "0 flockfile"). The crash always seems to be around CMPL or JMP in the assembly.

I'm intending to use it in this way:

```
+ (void)saveProfile:(NSString *)reason {
    DebugLog(@"Saved profile: %@", reason);
}
```

But I even get a crash when I do the following:

```
+ (void)saveProfile:(NSString *)reason {
    DebugLog(@"Saved profile.");
}
```

I noticed that I seem to always get Summary Unavailable on the NSString when I get the crash, but NSLog does still work if I put it in place of this other log. I've had NSLog in these locations for weeks, always logging out the saving of profiles to the console, but now that I've tried to replace it, I get this crash.

I've replaced all my NSLogs and almost all of them work fine. I'm trying to spot a pattern, and it seems like it could be always in class-level methods that it crashes. As far as I know, I've not done anything fancy with my Profile class. It derives NSObject, and has only class methods.

I originally had the import for this logging function as the last thing in my Prefix PCH file, and wondered if that was causing the problem, so I made all my files that used the function now import the header, and it's no longer in the PCH.

One other thing I tried is to replace (NSString *) with id as the first argument, as I read a CFStringAppendFormatCore post being about passing something other than NSString when NSString is expected. That made some sense, as I sometimes pass an NSObject in the additional arguments that I presume is logged via [theNsObject description]. But even reducing my code to the second example above, with no format - just a string literal - the crash still happens.

One last thing - this is running on iPhone 6.0 Simulator, with iOS 6 SDK and Xcode 4.5.2.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!